# Non-deprecated alternatives for <dl compact>

Tags: html, css

From Internet Explorer I fondly remember the possibility to create compact definition lists with code like

```
<dl compact>
    <dt>f</dt>
        <dd>Firefox</dd>
    <dt>i</dt>
        <dd>Internet Explorer</dd>
</dl>
```

with the results looking like this:

[image]

But alas, no current browser seems to support this feature; [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) does not even list the element as deprecated.

Firefox instead shows the definition details below the term:

[image: non-compact]

I tried using CSS like this:

```
dl>dd {
    margin-top: -1em;
}
```

and it almost works, but the term and details do not line up nicely:

[image: almost compact]

Is there a CSS (or other) solution to come closer to the Internet Explorer `<dl compact>` that does not rely on fiddling with funny `margin-top` values?

Comment: You can actually see that I, in fact, used two different browsers to render the examples: The kerning is different, especially that of 'I' and 'n' in 'Internet'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer based on floats.

It even supports multiple `<dt>` elements followed by a single `<dd>`, and supports a single `<dt>` followed by multiple `<dt>` elements.

And it will do a line break if there would be less than 1em of space between the `<dt>` and `<dd>` on the same line.

I can't guarantee that it will work in ever single situation for you, but they do nest at least one level deep.  And I've also tested this in default box-sizing and `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
dl[compact] dt {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
dl[compact] dd {
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin-left: 1em;
}
dl[compact]::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>ZZ</p>
<dl compact>
    <dt>AA</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dt>BBB</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dt>CC</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dt>DDDDDDDD</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dd>
        lorem ipsum dolor
        <dl compact>
            <dt>EE</dt>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dt>FFF</dt>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dt>GG</dt>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dt>HHHHHHHH</dt>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dt>LL</dt>
            <dt>MMMMMMMM</dt>
            <dt>NN</dt>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
            <dt>PPPPPPPP</dt>
            <dt>RR</dt>
            <dt>SSSSSSSS</dt>
            <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dt>TT</dt>
    <dt>UUUUUUUU</dt>
    <dt>VV</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dt>WWWWWWWW</dt>
    <dt>XX</dt>
    <dt>YYYYYYYY</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
</dl>
<p>ZZ</p>
<dl compact>
    <dt>AA</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
    <dt>BBBBBBBB</dt>
    <dd>lorem ipsum dolor</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to styling a compact description list that will keep things vertically aligned (even with different width terms) would be to use CSS Grid with rules for placing the terms and descriptions in their respective columns. It even works for lists that contain terms with multiple descriptions.

```css
dl.compact {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto;
  width: fit-content;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
dl.compact dt {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
dl.compact dd {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl class="compact">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Jean-Luc Picard</dd>
  <dt>Rank</dt>
  <dd>Captain</dd>
  <dt>Postings</dt>
  <dd>USS Reliant</dd>
  <dd>USS Stargazer</dd>
  <dd>USS Enterprise-D</dd>
  <dd>USS Enterprise-E</dd>
  <dt>Sons</dt>
  <dd>Thomas Picard</dd>
  <dd>Matthew Picard</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to change them from `block` to inline.

```css
dl[compact] dt,
dl[compact] dd {
  display: inline;
}


/* this makes the break between items */

dl[compact] dt:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<dl compact>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <dd>Firefox</dd>
  <dt>i</dt>
  <dd>Internet Explorer</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Using `dt:before { ... block; }` to cause a line break is great!
I'm gonna fiddle around with that; as is, it is not yet optimal (different-length `<dt>`'s cause the details to not line up horizontally, but with some `min-width` it should work. Thanks!

Comment: @Iziminza other options would be to make them table cells i think (in css)

Comment: That's another great idea.
Now I tried a simple `dl[compact] dt { position: absolute; }`. That feels like cheating, but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be using grid.

```css
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

dl {
  column-gap: 1rem;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <dd>Firefox</dd>
  <dt>i</dt>
  <dd>Internet Explorer</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Why use `inline-grid` instead of `grid`? This makes stray non-paragraphed text after the list show up to the right of the list.